# R 64 bit for Windows comparison

Tags: r

So there is R for 64-bit Windows users now. I'd like to know if anyone has found incremental benefits in using R-64bit over the 32bit version on Windows.

I'm looking for more specific information

- What was the system specification (6gb RAM for example) and the largest data-set that was crunched ?
- Which algorithm performed faster ?
- Any other experiential information that motivated you to adopt the 64bit version on Windows

If I had a $ for all the times non-R users cribbed about R's data limitation....!

I want to showcase R at my workplace and want some testimonials to prove that with a decently powerful machine, 64bit R on windows can crunch gigabyte class datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have anything quantitative, but it's been well worth the upgrade. 64-bit Windows  (7) is far more reliable and you can simply run more large jobs at once. The main advantage in 64-bit R is the ability to create large objects that don't hit the 32-bit limit. I have 12Gb of RAM and have worked with objects ~ 8Gb in size, for simple tests. Usually I wouldn't have any R process using more than 1-2Gb but the overall performance is great.

I'd be happy to run examples if you want specifics.

Comment: and btw, with R 2.11 the ability to draw very large arrays with rasterImage without calling rect for every pixel is a huge improvement.